# DXGI_FORMAT in dds file

Tags: image-processing, dds-format

I am parsing DDS file to read its header data. I want to modify format of image, but it seems that header mentioned at [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not specify where DXGI_FORMAT (internal format) is stored. Where I can I get internal format in file ?

Like DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM value is 71, but i did not find it in header

Comment: Did you check [`DDS_HEADER_DXT10`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943983(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @RogerRowland what if its not DXT10 ?